# AWK/SED that will match MAC addresses from a CSV file that are in a show MAC address-table

Tags: macos, csv, awk

I have a csv file with MAC addresses and I need a script to check if MAC addresses from csv file match those on output from a `show mac address-table` on a Cisco switch. If any of the MAC addresses from the csv file show up in the output, then pull those mac addresses and create a new csv file that shows where the MAC address is.

`show MAC address-table` output looks like this:

```
vlan     Mac Address     Type    Ports
-----    -----------     -----    -----
All      0011.2233.4455  STATIC   Gi1/1
All      0011.2233.4466  STATIC   CPU
All      0011.2233.4477  STATIC   CPU
All      0011.2233.4488  STATIC   Gi1/10
```

I would need to target the MACs and compare them to a csv file looking like this:

```
0011.2233.4455
0011.2233.4488
```

Then it creates a new csv file that lists what port its connected to.

```
All      0011.2233.4455  STATIC   Gi1/1
All      0011.2233.4488  STATIC   Gi1/10
```

Answer (score 2):

grep seems to be most simple:

```
grep -Ff maclist.txt address-table.txt
```

That is:

- `-F` to make grep search for fixed strings rather than regexes, and
- `-f maclist.txt` to make it read those strings from `maclist.txt` rather than the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat mac.txt | xargs -I{} grep {} address.table
```

assume you run the command on osx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} $2 in a' maclist.txt address-table.txt
All      0011.2233.4455  STATIC   Gi1/1
All      0011.2233.4488  STATIC   Gi1/10
```

`FNR==NR` for the first file `maclist.txt`, store it in array `a`
`$2 in a` test if second field in `address-table.txt` in array `a`,
if so, do default action, print the line.